# BigQuery Python client - meaning of timeout parameter, and how to set query result timeout

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-python

This question is about the `timeout` parameter in the `result` method of QueryJob objects in the BigQuery Python client.

It looks like the meaning of `timeout` has changed in relation to version 1.24.0.

For example, the [documentation for QueryJob's `result` in version 1.24.0](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/1.24.0/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.job.QueryJob.html#google.cloud.bigquery.job.QueryJob.result) states that timeout is:

> The number of seconds to wait for the underlying HTTP transport before using retry. If multiple requests are made under the hood, timeout is interpreted as the approximate total time of all requests.

As I understand it, this could be used as a way to limit the total time that the `result` method call will wait for the results.

For example, consider the following script:

```
import logging

from google.cloud import bigquery

# Set logging level to DEBUG in order to see the HTTP requests
# being made by urllib3
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

PROJECT_ID = "project_id" # replace by actual project ID

client = bigquery.Client(project=PROJECT_ID)

QUERY = ('SELECT name FROM `bigquery-public-data.usa_names.usa_1910_2013` '
        'WHERE state = "TX" '
        'LIMIT 100')
TIMEOUT = 30  # in seconds
query_job = client.query(QUERY)  # API request - starts the query
assert query_job.state == 'RUNNING'

# Waits for the query to finish
iterator = query_job.result(timeout=TIMEOUT)
rows = list(iterator)

assert query_job.state == 'DONE'
```

As I understand it, if all the API calls involved in fetching the results added up to more than 30 seconds, the call to `result` would give up. So, `timeout` here serves to limit the total execution time of the `result` method call.

However, later versions introduced a change. For example, the [documentation for `result` in 1.27.2](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/1.27.2/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.job.QueryJob.html#google.cloud.bigquery.job.QueryJob.result) states that timeout is:

> The number of seconds to wait for the underlying HTTP transport before using retry. If multiple requests are made under the hood, timeout applies to each individual request.

If I'm understanding this correctly, the example above changes meaning completely, and the call to `result` could potentially take more than 30 seconds.

My doubts are:

1. What exactly is the difference of the script above if I run it with the new version of `result` versus the old version?
2. What are the currently recommended use cases for passing a `timeout` value to `result`?
3. What is the currently recommended way to time out after a given total time while waiting for query results?

Thank you.

Comment: If the answer helped you somehow, consider accepting or upvoting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in this [fix](https://github.com/googleapis/python-bigquery/commit/a17be5f01043f32d9fbfb2ddf456031ea9205c8f):

> A transport layer timeout is made independent of the query timeout,
> i.e. the maximum time to wait for the query to complete.
>
> The query timeout is used by the blocking poll so that the backend
> does not block for too long when polling for job completion, but the
> transport can have different timeout requirements, and we do not want
> it to be raising sometimes unnecessary timeout errors.
>
> - Apply timeout to each of the underlying requests
>
> As job methods do not split the timeout anymore between all requests a
> method might make, the Client methods are adjusted in the same way.

So the basic difference is that in the previous version, if many requests were made in layer below they would share a 30 seconds timeout. In other words, if the first request takes 20 seconds, the second would timeout in 10 seconds.
In the new version every single request will have 30 seconds.

About the use case, basically it depends on your application. If you can not wait a long time for a request that might be lost you can decrease you timeout.